# Extracting values in a set/list that are not in the database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am well aware this is somewhat awkward, but I am looking for a way to know what are the values in a set that are not in a table of my DB, in other words, I need something like this : given a table "table" and a column "column", let's suppose "column" have a domain of {"a","b"} (these are the values that all the rows of "column" take for the attribute "column") and if we hand it a set (how to do that?) (let's say the set is {"a","b","c","d"}) the return will be a a table "table" with a column "column" and the two results "c" and "d" on the rows.

Any chance this can be done by an sql request ? 
I imagine this can be doable with Oracle's Dual table, but since I am working on Postgres, I sort of need some fancy trick.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a kind of "virtual table" with the [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-srf.html) function.

```
SELECT s.a as "column"
FROM generate_series(ascii('a'), ascii('d')) AS s("column")
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t
  ON chr(s."column") = t."column"
WHERE t."column" IS NULL;
```

That query is not tested, but it should get you started.

---

Re your comment:

If you have an arbitrary list of values, not a series of consecutive values, you could turn it into a *common table expression* (this solution was already posted by another user, but they then deleted their answer).

```
WITH s AS (
  SELECT 'a' AS "column" UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' 
)
SELECT s.a as "column"
FROM s
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t
  ON s."column" = t."column"
WHERE t."column" IS NULL;
```

Yes, you'll have to write application code to format a query from your list of input values.

Comment: +1 for teaching me the generate_series function, still, I feel I haven't explained clearly my idea, my goal is to enter a list (either manually or from a .csv file for example and compare its values with those present in the DB (having, in return, a table with the values that are in the input list and not in the DB). I think it's not doable in pur SQL and we need a third party programming language to do this type of work.